# Getting error while running cordova from commandline

Tags: node.js, cordova

I am running cordova from commandline on windows 7. I insalled it using nodejs.

But I get the error 
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Add npm path in system environment variable path.maybe it will help you.

C:\Users\Account\AppData\Roaming\npm;